# Incompatible types and System.out.print error?

Tags: java

The point of this assignment was to create a program that allowed a person to enter their first, and last name, and their year of birth. We had to create a user id with the first letter of their first name, the first three letters of the last name, and the last 2 digits of the birth year. For example, `Austin Carlile, 1987` --> `ACar87`.
 Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class UserID {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        int userID;

        System.out.print("Enter Your First Name: ");
        String s1 = input.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Enter Your Last Name: ");
        String s2 = input.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Enter Your year of birth: ");
        String s3 = input.nextLine();

        s1 = s1.substring(0, 1);
        s2 = s2.substring(0, 3);
        s3 = s3.substring(2, 4);

        userID = s1 + s2 + s3;

        System.out.print("The User's ID is: %userID", userID);
    }

}
```

I've switched my program around a bit trying to fix the error that I get so if anything seems obviously wrong, forgive me.

The errors I'm getting are:
 `error: incompatible types with the userID = s1 + s2 + s3` line, and the carat is under the last +.

The other is: `error: no suitable method found for print(String,int)` which is for   `System.out.print("The User's ID is: %userID", userID);` and the carat is under the second period in the `System.out.print`.

Can anyone help me figure this out?

Comment: `userID` is `int`, it should be `String` !

Answer (score 3):

Make `userId` as `String`. Your problem should be solved.
And when you print u don't pass another parameter. Append it.

```
 System.out.print("The User's ID is: " + userID);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. `userID` should be a `String`.  This way, you can concatenate the values of `s1`, `s2`, and `s3` to it.
2. `System.out.print("The User's ID is: %userID" + userID);` is close, but still syntactically incorrect.  If you want to do positional printing, then the method you're looking for is [`System.out.printf()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#printf%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29%29), and you want to make sure that you use the `%s` as mandated by the [`Formatter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax) class.

   ```
   System.out.printf("The User's ID is: %s", userID);
   ```

   ...but since there's only the one element, you should just concatenate the string literal with your variable in a `println` or `print` (but with the latter, and with the above, you need to include the `\n` character.

   ```
   System.out.print("The User's ID is: " + userID +  "\n");
   System.out.println("The User's ID is: " + userID);
   ```

Answer (score -1):

before 
System.out.print("The User's ID is : %userID"+ userID); <<< Grammar Error

After
System.out.printf("The User's ID is : %d",userID);

Comment: `System.out.print` doesn't support delimiters.  `System.out.printf` **does**.  And `%d` is for numerical values; if the fix is applied to `userID`, it becomes a `String`.

Comment: int userId change String userID

Answer (score -1):

You can't use formatter in print

you can use either

```
System.out.print("The User's ID is:"+ userID);
```

or if u want to use formatter you can use like

`System.out.printf("The User's ID is: %d",userID)`;